# convert visual studio C++ dll project to exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a C++ dynamic library that I want to use in Unity3D, except I'm encountering an error somewhere in it and would like to debug it in visual studio. To do this, I would like to convert the VS2010 project temporarily into an .exe project. What steps would I need to follow to do this? I've already tried changing the target extension, linker output file, and set the entry point but it just won't start.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. Since it's your own DLL, and you have the source for it, you should be able to build the DLL with debug information. You should do some research in VS2010 documentation and MSDN on how this is done. You do need to create an exe that loads the DLL of course if you haven't already.

Comment: Why not just build a simple test app (exe) that simply loads your DLL and calls the appropriate DLL exports?

Comment: I suppose that would be a better way to do this, but can you be more specific on which articles I should read in the VS2010 and MSDN documentation on how to use debug information? Also, I know how to call methods that are defined in header files of DLLs, but the functions unity needs to call are "extern "C"" methods, which are not defined in header files. How would I call those?

Comment: @bogeyc Tried using your method. The reason I wanted to just convert the project instead of linking the dll to a new exe is because I don't want to have to deal with linking. I've been getting lnk2019 errors whenever trying to call a function in it. Is there any way at all to just convert the dll project? I feel I would have been done with this by now.

Comment: Wirite test with some framework like Gtest or Boost Test, and then you can debug a single function

Answer (score 0):

Found that I can attach the VS debugger to Unity3D process, which does what I need.